# Check/Trigger when page height changes

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, height, watch

**Case:**

I was searching the web for re-sizing the iframe based on its content (iframe and the page hosting are from the same domain). What I found as the possible working solution is to call a function of parent window from iframe sending the size to set height for the iframe. That is simple to implement.

**Problem:**

The problem now is that the page loading inside iframe is AJAX intensive and is dependent on user's interaction on the page. The height can increase or decrease relative to user's actions (note that height only changes on user interaction and not randomly or automatically). Now I want to trigger a function when the height of "body" (of page inside iframe) changes the height. This would help me to re-size the iframe every time the height changes inside it.

**Possible Solutions:**

I tried using

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    document.body.watch("clientHeight", function(property, oldHeight, newHeight) {
        alert('New Height: ' + newHeight);
    });
});
```

but the function never triggers. Even I get it to work, from what I found on internet, it does not work on IE. I want a solution that at-least works for IE8.

Another possible solution was to watch the user's interaction on the events that could cause the change of height. But that would be really inefficient as there are a-lot of such events that could cause height changes.

So what is the best way to go around it?

Regards

Jehanzeb

Comment: See the [big red warning here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch)? **"Generally you should avoid using watch() and unwatch() when possible. These two methods are implemented only in Gecko, and they're intended primarily for debugging use. In addition, using watchpoints has a serious negative impact on performance"**

Comment: Yes I understood that when I posted the question. And I actually never found an answer to my question. The solutions that I had in my mind were either a load on the client's browser. Or was so slow that it felt as a glitch in program. We had to eventually move off of the iframe. :(

Comment: Jehanzeb I was actually looking for the same and it seems there is no solution, apart from the continuous polling in certain time intervals. Much better than `watch` but not ideal anyway.

Comment: @Tomas, yes I also tried polling. I actually wanted to avoid multiple scroll-bars on a single page. Polling on an interval of 500ms kind of produced a glitch where scroll-bar would show and then disappear. And due to vertical scroll bar, page width changed and that had affect on page design. Polling lower than this just seemed meaningless. I hate when I have to use time/delays in my code.

Comment: Jehanzeb exactly. Another solution (which I will follow) is to handle all possible places in your code where you can change the page height and generate some custom event yourself.